# Overriding !important property used in widget stylesheet in the footer

Tags: css, css-cascade

I have a twitter widget which is loaded into the footer of my page. The problem is that it uses !important properties all over the place. And because my stylesheets are all loaded into the head, the widget's style sheets automatically override any of mine.

Do I really have to put a couple of separate styles in the footer of my document, below the widget, to get force this. Or is there a more semantic method?

Comment: When `!important` abuse comes into play, you can safely and easily forget about semantics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would go through and see if there is a way to make your CSS more [specific](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#specificity) than the selectors used in twitter. The rules of specificity will ensure that your `!important` styles override the twitter `!important` styles.

Otherwise, as a last resort and if `!important` is only used on classes in the Twitter CSS then you could assign an `id` to anything that is overridden to ensure that your selectors are more specific.

```
/* your style */
#anti_twitter a.link {
    color: blue !important;
}

/* twitter style */
a.link {
    color: red !important;
}
```

So using the code above, the links would come out blue.

**JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9T9uk/**

Answer (score 1):

```
<div id="myWrapper">
     <div id="theDefaultId">
       ....
     </div>
</div>
```

and you can use `#myWrapper #theDefaultId { anything: value !important; }`

`theDefaultId` is the id which the twitter widget uses and `#myWrapper` is an id defined by us.

This should work.